# to find coefficient of $X^r$ in $\frac {1}{(1-5X)^3}$

Tags: combinatorics

I am bit confused how to find coefficient of $X^r$ in $\frac {1}{(1-5X)^3}$. If it was $\frac {1}{(1-X)^3}$, then it is equal to $(1+X+X^2+...)(1+X+X^2+...)(1+X+X^2+...)$, then coefficient of $X^r$ is same as number of ways to distribute r similar balls into 3 numbered boxes which is same as no. of integer solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3=r$ which is C(2+r,r). But I am stuck with given problem. Any hint.

Comment: oh..i got it...just have to replace X by 5X

Answer (score 1):

$$(1+z)^{-p}=1+{-p \choose 1}z+{-p \choose 2} z^2+ {-p \choose 3}+ ..+{-p \choose k}z^k+..$$ ad-in, $p$ is  integer and $|z|<1.$ Most importantly $${-p \choose k} = (-1)^k{p +k-1 \choose k},~ if~ p\in I^+$$

Comment: @Believer Oh! thanks you are right, see my edit.